# elasticsearch ngram backslash escape

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using a ngram analysier on my elastic search index. This is needed for the search capablity I require. I am searching for a document with a name called "l/test_V0001". When  I search using "l/test" i am only getting results for "l" the / is working as a escape character and not as a text. I have searched and found this is a common issue and expected but can find no work around.

When i search the API for "l/test_V0001" I can find the result I am after. However when doing the same search via the java API I still only get results for "l".

here is the API search:

```
 {
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "l/test_V0001",
            "fields": ["name", "name.partial", "name.text"]
        }
    }
}
```

and the mapping for the index:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "max_ngram_diff": 20,
      "search.idle.after": "10m"
    },
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "ngram3_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "ngram3_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "ngram3_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 20
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "fields": {
          "partial": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "ngram3_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "keyword"
          },
          "text": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      },
      "value": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

any help on this or a work around would be great!

Comment: can you show your jaba code which is not working ?

Comment: @Prerna added into the question

Answer (score 0):

so after a bit of digging I found the answer using custom token chars. This is has added to the index mapping:

```
"tokenizer": {
        "ngram3_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 20,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit",
            "symbol",
            "custom"
          ],
          "custom_token_chars": "/"
        }
```

so my full index now looks like:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "max_ngram_diff": 20,
      "search.idle.after": "10m"
    },
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "ngram3_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "ngram3_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "ngram3_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 20,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit",
            "symbol",
            "custom"
          ],
          "custom_token_chars": "/"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "fields": {
          "partial": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "ngram3_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "keyword"
          },
          "text": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      },
      "value": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this works for both rest client and java API